# Call javascript from webview in MainActivity Xamarin

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.ios

I trying to call a javascript function from webview in a mainactivity. This where is possible in my custom Render, just calling this.Element.Eval("alert('')").

I cant call FindViewById becaus webview is not available in Resouces.Id.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is your `WebView` type ? `Xamarin.Forms.WebView` or `Android.Webkit.WebView` ?

Comment: Hello, its a Xamarin.Forms.WebView

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.forms.WebView offer the [Eval()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.Eval/p/System.String/) method to call JavaScript from C#, here's the official doucmentation: [Call JavaScript from C#](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/call-javascript/).

> I cant call FindViewById becaus webview is not available in Resouces.Id.

Use `x:Name` to name your control in XAML, like this:

`<WebView x:Name="webView" ... />`

Then you can use it in the behind C# code via the name, like this:

`webView.Eval (string.Format ("printMultiplicationTable({0}, {1})", number, end));`